# Regex anchors in GitLab Push Rules

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I hope you're doing well,

I'm new in GitLab, I'm trying to add a Push Rules in order to Restrict push operations. I have this regex:

```
^(build|test)(: ([a-z].{0,70}[^\\.]\s+))(\((JIRA|CARD)-[0-9]+)\)\n$\n(^Team: (Dragons|Eagles))$
```

and it is configured in GitLab, this is a correct commit message

```
test: testing commit message (JIRA-1235)

Team: Dragons
```

But if I send a commit message like this one:

```
test: testing commit message (JIRA-1235)

Team: Dragons

test: testing commit message (JIRA-1235)

Team: Dragons
```

Since the regex match the commit/push is success, how can I limit the regex just a one match and do not allow multi messages/matches.

Comment: I know nothing about GitLab CI, but according to [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/15827) it uses the *re2* engine, which [supports](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) `\A` and `\z` (match the very start and the very end of the string). Try replacing `^` and `$` with them correspondingly. If that works for you, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @InSync looks like the \Z is not recognized:
Commit message regex not valid RE2 syntax: invalid escape sequence: \Z

Comment: It's `\z` with a lowercase `z`. `\Z` is indeed not supported, as specified in the syntax documentation I linked above.

Comment: Right it worked with \z, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab CI [uses the *re2* engine](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/15827); this engine [supports](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) the `\A` and `\z` anchors, which match the very start and the very end of the string, correspondingly. Simply use them instead of `^` and `$`. That said, the new regex should look something like this:

```
\A
(build|test)(: ([a-z].{0,70}[^\\.]\s+))(\((JIRA|CARD)-[0-9]+)\)
\n\n
(Team: (Dragons|Eagles))
\z
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/F6vaNa/1).

Note that it's `\z` with a lowercase `z`. This is easily confusable with `\Z`, which, in supported engines such as PCRE and .NET, matches either the end of the string (same as `\z`) or the position before the last line terminator if it is also the last character of the string.